# Can I edit the powers values with Coalesced Editor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

For example, can I increase the armor rating of tech armor or fortification powers?

Comment: Please don't answer your question by editing the answer in the question body :) There is a handy 'Answer your question' button at the bottom for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Always backup your character save files and original coalesced.bin file before making changes to the coalescend.bin files...

1. List item Google and download your favorite coalesced editor for mass effect
2. Using the editor, navigate to:

   ```
   biogame.ini > sfxgamecontent > sfxpowercustomaction
   ```
3. All the powers are listed there, and you can edit them to your heart's content. (Just be careful to heed the warning above....)